# Can EntityFramework send all queries in one shot?

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, entity-framework

We have a system where we have 8 tables. In each context we will either insert / update few of the 8 tables. As I see in the logs, entity framework is sending multiple queries one by one in sequence to update each table. Is there a way that entity framework to send all queries in one go to the database and get the status? 
In my view this will improve the performance by whole lot as we are avoiding the network calls.

FYI, our system is a multi threaded where each thread has its own context to update these 8 tables. Since there are multiple queries to DB for a single context (i.e., thread) it is becoming very slow.

Any suggestions are welcome and much appreciated.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think it's something they want to introduce in EF7

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 2):

Multiple queries to the database, from a single context, is probably not the reason your query execution is slow. In general, most of projects have similar scenarios, where a single database context runs multiple DML queries using entity framework.

Please use an SQL Profiler to identify which query is causing the issue. It might be some bad joins or an invalid condition, which is creating the issue.

Also you have to verify the database server configuration; that is, how much load your server can handle.

Comment: If I have a single thread then context saving is taking 7 ms. But If I have few hundreds of threads (each thread having its own context and try to save to DB) the context save on an average is taking 300 ms. This can be the DB issue and also multiple network calls (sql quereies) per each thread.. We are confident that the data and indexes are  correct on the DB side so we suspect the network delays here..

Comment: You are correct.. the slow query execution can be based on network delay also it can be hardware related (i.e. configuration of your DB server).

Comment: Yes, so we spent good amount of time to improve the DB performance and we reached a point where we couldn't improve more so now we are looking at improving the network delays..

Comment: When i  say DB server configuration i don't mean database. I mean Quad Core, Octa Core or Hexa Core processor, how much ram you have, what's normal load on the server etc etc.... For example quad core processor with 4Gb ram will never take the load what hexa core with 16gb ram can take

Comment: We have huge RAM size of 128 GB.. I limited the SQL Max Memory size to 90GB... There will not be anyother load apart from the application I am running...

Answer (score 1):

You can try **.NET Entity Framework Extensions** (not free).

http://www.zzzprojects.com/products/dotnet-development/entity-framework-extensions/

They batch multiple queries in one and use bulk operations to improve performances.

Here is an example from their site:

```
// Upgrade SaveChanges performance with BulkSaveChanges
var context = new CustomerContext();
// ... context code ...

// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(operation => operation.BatchSize = 1000);
```